# How to obtain a private key for a legacy Google App Engine project?

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api

I have a Google App Engine app which was created in early January 2013. I now want to use the Google Calendar API to post calendar entries from my GAE app and - after reading about the various options - I decided that Service Accounts with OAuth 2.0 authentication would be the best option. This approach requires the use of a private key to sign a JSON data structure with various credentials.

Now the [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount) states:

```
During the creation of a service account, you will be prompted 
to download a private key.
```

I checked my GAE dashboard and can see that there's a service account associated with it but I cannot remember ever being prompted to download a private key. I checked the Google Cloud Dashboard but could not find any links to obtaining such a key either.

Is it possible to obtain the required key at this moment and if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new service account in the console.

Answer (score 4):

I have accepted Zig's answer and although it is slightly brief it helped me find a solution for this. For people who run into the same issue, here's some more detailed information

I initially could not find anything in the Cloud Console but then - after another hour of wading through Google's documentation and Cloud Console - found the relevant pages in the **Api Console** which is a different beast.

In the **API Console** click API access from the side bar. Then click the "Create another Client ID..." button and choose "Service Account". This will popup a window which allows you to download the private key.

Comment: sorry in the old days that was the only console :)