# Sample of Server to Server authentication using OAuth 2.0 with Google API's

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth

This is a follow-up question for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19391252/how-to-obtain-a-private-key-for-a-legacy-google-app-engine-project):

I have successfully created a private key and have read the various pages of Google documentation on the concepts of server to server authentication.

I need to create a JWT to authorize my App Engine application (Python) to access the Google calendar and post events in the calendar. From the source in `oauth2client` it looks like I need to use `oauth2client.client.SignedJwtAssertionCredentials` to create the JWT.

What I'm missing at the moment is a stylised bit of sample Python code of the various steps involved to create the JWT and use it to authenticate my App Engine application for Google Calendar. Also, from `SignedJwtAssertionCredentials` source it looks like I need some App Engine compatible library to perform the signing.

Can anybody shed some light on this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some digging I found a [couple of samples](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/source/browse/#hg/samples/service_account) based on the OAuth2 authentication. From this I cooked up the following simple sample that creates a JWT to access the calendar API:

```
import httplib2
import pprint

from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials

# Get the private key from the Google supplied private key file.
f = file("your_private_key_file.p12", "rb")
key = f.read()
f.close()

# Create the JWT
credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
  "xxxxxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com", key,
  scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"
)

# Create an authorized http instance
http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)

# Create a service call to the calendar API
service = build("calendar", "v3", http=http)

# List all calendars.
lists = service.calendarList().list(pageToken=None).execute(http=http)
pprint.pprint(lists)
```

For this to work on Google App Engine you will need to enable PyCrypto for your app. This means adding the following to your `app.yaml` file:

```
libraries:
- name: pycrypto
  version: "latest"
```

Comment: Thanks for the pycrypto lib trick. Couldn't make SignedJwtAssertionCredentials work >_<